# set numbers of admin.TabularInline in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

how can I set numbers of `admin.Tabularline` in `django admin`? in default, it shows 3 empty rows and i just want to show only 1 empty row.

```
class ClientPaymentOptionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ClientPaymentOption
    fields = ('name', 'action','percent', 'fixamount', 'itemcharged', 'client')
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #display list
    list_display = ('name','b_type','banner','logo',
                    'contact','address','account_type',
                    'status','currency','color','user',
                    )
    #display fields
    fields = ('name','b_type','banner','logo','contact',
              'address','account_type','status',
              'currency','color','user',
              )
    inlines = [ClientPaymentOptionInline]

admin.site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Set your inline's `extra` attribute to 1.

Comment: thanks thomas, i insert `extra=1` in my `ClientPaymentOptionInline`

Comment: if i edit a client probably will add more row (ClientPaymentOption). How can i simply use a number of rows by default without using 'extra'  since that will add allways one more row even when i'm just editing.